# Lock-free implementation of a Thread Library

Tags: java, python, c, concurrency, lock-free

I have been going through a few published papers which details algorithms and data structures which can be used for implementation of a thread library. I searched online to view any existing implementation of the same, and I could only find LFThreads(only its documentation, not its source code).

Have any of you worked on/used a lock-free thread library? I would like to go through its source and a see a few examples of how exactly it is used.

Comment: What do you mean by 'thread library'?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Intel Threading Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org)? It's C++, which is not in your tags, but I thought you might be interested since it's open source.